# Helpful Zugzwang?

Tags: zugzwang

Are there positions where a zugzwang helps the zugzwang'ed player? For instance, white forces black to make a move that gives black an advantage. Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Brian Towers wrote, a zugzwang by definition can't be helpful to the recipient, but if we go past the terminology and look at your second question: "white forces black to make a move that gives black an advantage. Is that possible?", the answer is yes. You can even force the other player to checkmate you; there's even a class of chess problems called *[selfmates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfmate)*.

Answer (score 5):

No.

If you look up the [meaning of "zugzwang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang) you will see something like

> Zugzwang (German for "compulsion to move") is a situation found in
>   chess and other games wherein one player is put at a disadvantage
>   because they must make a move when they would prefer to pass and not
>   move. The fact that the player is compelled to move means that their
>   position will become significantly weaker. A player is said to be "in
>   zugzwang" when any possible move will worsen their position.

So, by definition if there is only one legal move and it makes your position better then it is not zugzwang.